# Can find my answer. Laptop boot issues to external monitor

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, multiple-monitors, laptop

I run a Xidax laptop dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 19.04.

Never used linux before so I need an easy break down on this.

How can I make my laptop force the boot grub to an external monitor only when the monitors are plugged in?

I keep having to open my lid to do all the boot prompts like selecting an OS and signing in.

I am running one monitor HDMI and the other is on a mini display port (vga to mini display adapter)

Can someone give me a step by step break down on where to go and what to enter in to make this work.  I want my laptop monitor to know to work when the externals are not plugged in as well if possible.

PC specs -

Processor Intel Core i7-770HQ CPU @ 2.80 GHZ x 8 
Graphics GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2
Gnome 3.32.1
OS 64 bit Ubuntu 19.04

Running an ASUS 23 inch monitor on HDMI

and

ACER 24" monitor on mini display port adapter from VGA

If you need more info please tell me what you need and how to find it for you.

Thanks.

Comment: My Xrandr command yielded these results.

Comment: creen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm

Comment: 1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81

Comment: 1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm

Comment: DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: There was more but too much to paste here